# Match using particular words and suppress the text if found set of negative terms using Regex python

Tags: python, regex

Example:

Text1:
Receipt and drafting of correspondence from Mr. Sharma re: availability for settlement conference.

Text2:
Receipt and review of correspondence from Mr. Sharma re: availability for settlement conference.

**Question:** If a line contains words like "attend%","confer%" or "call%" anywhere in the line then it should find a match but if the same line also contains word like "check%" and "draft%" anywhere in that line then it should ignore that line.

Hence, Text 1 should not match since it contains word "drafting", while Text should match because it does not contain the suppression terms like check% and draft%

Tried this :`(\battend|\bconfer|\bcall)(?!.*?\b(check|draf)).*`

I need single line regex solution in python for this. Anyone would like to help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your negative lookahead assertion at the beginning of a line instead:

```
^(?!.*(?:\bcheck|\bdraf)).*(\battend|\bconfer|\bcall)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/EtBSX4/1

Answer (score 0):

This expression does what you look for:

```
(?=(^(?:(?!\b(draft|check)).)*$))(?=.*?(\battend|\bconfer|\bcall))
```

you can use positive lookahead ( ?= ) to first check if whole line does not contain the filter words than look if your desired words exist.

Comment: Thank You @Aras for your effort but it looks very complicated to me. Though it is working fine.